For $z$ complex, do we have $\lim_{|z| < 1, \, z \to 1} (1 - z) \Big( \sum_{m = 0}^\infty z^{m^2} \Big)^2 = \frac{\pi}{4}$?
Edit:
It is well known that for real variable $x$, $\lim_{x \to 1^-} (1 - x) \Big( \sum_{m = 0}^\infty x^{m^2}  \Big)^2 = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

I would like to know whether this limit continues to hold if we instead let our variable $z$ be in $\mathbb{C}$. That is, do we have

$$\lim_{|z| < 1, \, z \to 1} (1 - z) \Big( \sum_{m = 0}^\infty z^{m^2}  \Big)^2 = \frac{\pi}{4}?$$
The most accessible proof I know of for the real case essentially utilizes the integral test for series. So we cannot directly apply it the complex case because the integral test requires a nonnegative, decreasing function as input.
The main problem seems to be oscillation in the sense that, even as $z \to 1$, the powers $z^{m^2}$ can have phases that are quite different from one another.
However, note that in the simpler case of a geometric series $\sum_{m =0}^\infty z^m = (1 -z)^{-1}$ these oscillations do not cause an issue, in the sense that $\lim_{|z|<1,\, z \to 1} (1 -z) \sum_{m =0}^\infty z^m = 1$. So I thought maybe there is some hope.
We can try to bootstrap back the real case:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\Big| \sqrt{1 - z}\sum_{m = 0}^\infty z^{m^2} -\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \Big| &\le  \Big| \sqrt{1 - x}\sum_{m = 0}^\infty x^{m^2} -\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \Big| \\
&+ \Big| \sqrt{1 - x}\sum_{m = 0}^\infty x^{m^2} - \sqrt{1 - z}\sum_{m = 0}^\infty z^{m^2} \Big|,
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
but it seems quite tricky to show that the last expression is small uniformly in the phase of $z$.
Original post:
I would like to understand the asymptotic for the series
$$\sum_{m =1}^\infty e^{-m^2/(\sigma + it)},$$
for $0 < \sigma \le 1$ and $ t \to \infty$. This series is similar to but a little different from the series representation for Jacobi's third theta function. The most helpful reference I have been able to find so far is this previous post, but the asymptotic quoted there does not quite apply to my situation.
If one replaces $m^2$ by $m$ then the asymptotic can be found immediately because in that case we just have a geometric series
$$\sum_{m =0}^\infty e^{-m/(\sigma + it)} = \frac{e^{-1/(\sigma + it)}}{1 - e^{-1/(\sigma + it)}} \sim (\sigma + it), \qquad 0 < \sigma \le 1, \, t \to \infty.$$
My guess is that having $m^2$ instead of $m$ will give
$$\sum_{m =1}^\infty e^{-m^2/(\sigma + it)} = O(|\sigma + it|^{1/2}).$$
I am familiar with the Poisson summation formula and Jacobi's theta function identity. I'm not sure if they are helpful here. Hints, references, or solutions are greatly appreciated.

your function is given by $2f(s)+1=\theta_0(-\frac{1}{i\pi s})$ with $s=\sigma+it, \theta_0(z)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z}e^{in^2\pi z}, \Im z >0$ so applying the usual inversion formula $\theta_0(z)=\frac{e^{i\pi/4}}{\sqrt z}\theta_0(-1/z)$ should give you the result you want easily

@Conrad Thank you for your comment. I had considered taking a route similar to this, but I think the catch is that it's not immediately clear what happens to $\theta_0(-1/z)$ as $\sigma \to 0^+$ and $t \to \infty$.

@Conrad Thanks again for the comment. I think I'm getting closer, but then don't we have $f(s) = \tfrac{1}{2} \theta_0(-\tfrac{1}{i\pi s}) - \tfrac{1}{2}$, which is  $\tfrac{e^{i\pi/4} \sqrt{-i \pi s}}{2} \theta_0(i\pi s) - \tfrac{1}{2}$. So I'm getting that the relevant sum is effectively $\sum e^{n^2(-\sigma + it)}$, which is troublesome as $\sigma \to 0^+$.

@Conrad That multiplication makes sense, but then substituting $z = i \pi s = \pi(-t + i\sigma)$ into $\theta_0(z) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{in^2 \pi z}$ is where I find trouble, because there is yet another $i$ factor, before the $n^2$ in the exponent, by which I need to multiply.

yes you are right and I was hasty - I guess that then you need to fix $\sigma$ or at least get the asymptotic for $\sigma \ge \delta>0$ and the $O$ depending on $\delta$
